# Getting fxml file used with a controller from the controller

Tags: javafx, fxml

How to get to know which fxml file called the controller class while multiple fxml files have same controller class?

I have an initialize class in which I would like to auto complete two text fields from  data in the database. As the controller class is same it throws an error when I run the program. So getting details about which fxml page called the controller class would help.

Comment: Can someone let me know what makes this question to have a down vote? I am not trying to criticize.. just out of curiosity want to know the reason.

Comment: You can use the same class as the controller for multiple FXML files, but you really *shouldn't* share the *same instance* of the controller class for multiple FXML. Lastly, the worst thing to do is to create a single controller class where you have things like `@FXML private Button buttonA` from A.fxml (**only from this FXML**) and `@FXML private Button buttonB` from B.fxml (and again **only from this FXML**). In general, FXML and controller *should* be a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Hi @ApthaJeevi and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please try to find a better title for this question? Like e.g. "How to identitfy fxml file from which my Controller was initialized"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the same controller class for different FXML files because then you won't need to deal with problems like this in the first place. However, if you insist you can manually call [FXMLLoader.setController](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController-java.lang.Object-) before loading the FXML (you also need to remove the reference to the controller inside the FXML), this way you know which controller instance is assigned to which FXML

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you specify the fxml to load by passing a `URL`, not an `InputStream`, you simply need to add a `URL location` field that `FXMLLoader` can inject a value to. `FXMLLoader` automatically injects the fxml url to this field:

```
@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    System.out.println(location);
}
```

Using the same controller for multiple fxmls with different functionality seems to be bad practice though. Please double check, if using different controllers wouldn't be a cleaner solution.

---

**Note:** Every time you load a fxml containing a `fx:controller` attribute with a controller class name as value, a ***new instance*** of the controller is created.